# Using absolute pathnames in java

Tags: java, absolute-path

When I ran a program in java that is supposed to read a file, the compiler warned me that the file isn't in the directory so I tried spelling out the files absolute pathname. I am a bit confused on how to type in an absolute pathname that contains spaces, such as Module 06. I know in Unix, you can either type it as Module\ 06 or "Module 06" so I tried both of these in Java. When I used the forward slash, the compiler warned me with an error of "illegal escape character" so I tried it with double forward slashes and when I tried it with the quotation marks, the compiler wouldn't like recognize the name in quotation marks. How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is what I am trying to fix:

```
"/Users/timothylee/Desktop/APCS\\ Course\\ Files/Module\\ 06/Mod06\\ Assignments/6.03\\ Weather\\ Data/src"
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape spaces if the file name is in quotes. You could have `new File("My File")`

Answer (score 0):

Use "/" instead of "\" when using directories because "\" is used for escape sequences
So it should look like:

```
"/Users/timothylee/Desktop/APCS/Course/Files/Module/06/Mod06/Assignments/6.03/Weather/Data/src
```